# Update SP list with data from external DB

Tags: caml-query, migration, datatable

The requirements include quick edit, so BCS and OOTB external list are not an option here.  The solution I'm looking for has to make these steps:

- foreach record in a datatable:

  - if the record exists in list: update it.
  - else: insert it to the list.

I figured out that SSOM iterations are not good performance here.. and I saw based on Caml query, (which seems to be much faster) kind of things but not exactly this one.
Can anyone help solve this issue ?..

Comment: You need to give a little more detail. Where is your performance issue occurring? What have you tried? How do you relate the DB table to the list? (if you don't maybe you should via item id or item GUID). If you are looking for specific items that match a string why not use search?

Comment: What's the data source for this data table!

Comment: I have done this in a C# console app using the SharePoint API (so it has to run on one of the servers). I can’t easily post the code. But for speed I read in the entire list and stored the field used as the “key” and the item ID in a dictionary then used that to compare the DB (SQL) values rather than querying the list for every DB row. This works if there are no adds/updates going on through the SharePoint UI.

Comment: @M.Qassas the data source is sql DB with data similar to the data in SP list

Comment: @mannaggia, on 1st mind, it's seems that compare id's always faster than compare the values in all fields themselves.. But, i will be very thankful if you'll can post your code sample. Thanks !